# finding nearest points in python

Tags: python, arrays

I started using Python recently so maybe this is a stupid question, but anyway:

I have two arrays `C` and `X`. Each array elements are two dimensional points.

for example:

```
C = [[1,1], [10,10]]

X = [[1,2], [1,3], [2,1], [10,11], [10,12], [11,11], [12,11], [9,11]]
```

I want to group points from `X` around nearest (euclidean distance) points in `C`.

for example nearest point from `C` for element 1 of `X([1,2])` is first element of `C( [1,1])`,

for second element of `X ([1,3])` -  again first element of `C([1,1])`

...

for last element in `X([9,11])` - second element in `C([10,10])`

so `[1,1]` is nearest element for 3 points form `X`, and `[10, 10]` is nearest for 5 elements from `X`.

I want a function in python `F(C,X)` that will return for every element of `C`, the number of elements from `X` to whom this element of `C` is nearest. So in this example it should return `[3,5]`.

I can write my own function but it will not be effective, so I'm interested if there is any predefined function in Python for my problem?

Thank you

Comment: Did you tried `scipy` ?

Comment: have you checked out numpy, scipy or pandas?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28207/finding-the-closest-point-to-a-list-of-points

Comment: thank you, spatial.KDTree does the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a faster, but this do the work:

```
import numpy as np

C = [[1,1], [10,10]]
X = [[1,2], [1,3], [2,1], [10,11], [10,12], [11,11], [12,11], [9,11]]

def F(C,X):
    Carr = np.array(C)
    Xarr = np.array(X)
    distances = [np.sum( (Xarr - Carr[i])**2, axis=1) for i in range(len(C))]
    closests = np.argmin( np.array(distances), axis=0 )
    return list( np.bincount(closests) )

print(F(C,X))
```

will print:

```
[3, 5]
```